# How can I render the output in a certain language in a Twig template?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I am trying to override the titles of the nodes on my view page for Drupal 8. As my whole website is in English, but only on one view page I need to fetch the french translation of the titles, without translating the whole interface.

For this I am overriding the `views-view-field.html.twig` template with custom `views-view-field--my-view--title.html.twig`.

In the preprocess function in `MYTHEME.theme` I am sending the language = 'fr':

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_field__MYVIEW__title(&$variables) {
  $variables['language'] = 'fr';
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'route';
}
```

The Twig template receives the language, but still displays titles in English. This is how my Twig template currently looks like. How can I say to fetch output in French?

```
{{ output }}
```

UPDATE:

thanks to Kint sub-module I could get all possible [image: tokens]. Now I need to fetch the right translation.

How can I reach french translation? I have tried already few options:

```
{{ row._entity.title.value.translation('fr') }}
{{ row._entity.title.value.fr }}
{{ row._entity.values.title.translation('fr') }}
{{ row._entity.values.title.fr }}
```

None of them is working. 
As I can see the values is an array, then it should be some special may accesing the elements inside

Comment: Please see the linked post. You can get the current language without preprocessing in Twig directly via `{{ language.getId() }}`.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you want. I'll update the title.

Comment: The current language is English, I don't need it

Comment: The answer to [How to render Entity Reference fields in the current language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/257653/15055) probably has your solution.

Comment: Have seen this post already. Replacing {{output}} with {{node.field_data.entity.translation('fr').title.value }}, and many other variations brings nothing.

Comment: Sure, calling `{{ node }}` in a view template won't do the trick. Do you know of Devel's sub-module Kint and calling `{{ kint() }}` in your template to get to see what values you have and how to possibly alter them?

Comment: Kint module is a very big discovery for me! Thanks a lot! Now I could print all possible options to replace the output. But still can not find the right chain how to reach french translation